# Pandas: need to remove the row that contains a string. BUT my condition is not working

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
from chainer import datasets
from chainer.datasets import tuple_dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import chainer
import pandas as pd 
import math
```

I have a file CSV contains 40300 data.

```
df =pd.read_csv("Myfile.csv", header = None)
```

in this area i am removing the ignored rows and columns

```
columns = [0,1]
rows = [0,1,2]
df.drop(columns, axis = 1, inplace = True) #drop the two first columns that no need to the code
df.drop(rows,  axis = 0, inplace = True) #drop the two first rwos that no need to the code
```

in this area i want to remove the row if string data type faced BUT its not working

```
df[~df.E.str.contains("Intf Shut")]~this part is not working with me 

df.to_csv('summary.csv', index = False, header = False)

df.head()
```

Comment: You need to assign it: `df = df[~df.E.str.contains("Intf Shut")]`

Answer (score 0):

You have to reassign the value of df in df

```
df = df[~df.E.str.contains("Intf Shut")]
```

Comment: Yes correct, What i have here it is : 

'df[~df[2].isin(to_drop)]'
so i have changed the column name into array which i choose the third column, 
Then I already define the "to_drop" to the specific word that contains Which its like following. 

'to_drop = ['My text 1', 'My text 2']'

Thanks dude for your answer

Answer (score 0):

have to change the column name into array which I choose the third column,

`df[~df[2].isin(to_drop)]`

Then you can define first a variable "to_drop" to the specific text that contains, Which its like following.

`to_drop = ['My text 1', 'My text 2']`